# Slack command URL not working via web browser

Tags: jenkins, slack

I am trying to execute a Jenkins job via slack.

I have integrated the command and the URL that I pass in the command is working via command line.

The same URL when I put in web browser is giving the error

```
Access Denied
Invalid Token Specified

[root@ip-172-31-40-187 jobs]# curl http://13.127.223.19:8080/job/startApacheServer/build?token=mytoken --user "piyu:1128fcb12815c3d891ed43dd4b982636e6"
[root@ip-172-31-40-187 jobs]# echo $?
0
```

The same is not working when I put it in browser and also slack commands exit with a status of 403